# I am making an apple crisp and need to know how much salt I need for 4 tsps baking powder

Tags: baking, leavening

I am making an apple crisp for my husband's restaurant. I'm using a recipe that I did not create. Recipe calls for 4 tsps baking powder, but there's no measurement for the salt! I know it needs salt to rise. Please help! This needs to be done asap.

Comment: It probably needs salt, but salt does not help baked goods to rise...and apple crisp generally is not a risen product. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

Just a large pinch of salt will be fine for both the crust and the filling. In the crust it helps with flavor, makes a buttery crust taste less oily, and it also helps with browning. In the filling it helps give a lift to the flavor.

Comment: Some explanation of why would improve this answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton. Thank you for the nudge — info added. I was just trying to get her an answer quickly for her bake while I had a minute.

Comment: What about the question of whether it helps the crisp to rise?

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. It's an apple crisp. Also, salt hinders yeast development, so the opposite would be true.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need salt at all. It is not needed for technical reasons - the recipe will rise without it. There are people who prefer to add salt to baked goods because they like the taste, but your recipe happens to not follow this tradition.

If you want to change the recipe, add salt to taste, you can use other recipes you've made to get an idea for a likely range. Or make it without salt and see if you like it that way too.